# C# Entity Framework Generic class -> reload all child entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, generic-programming

I currently have a multi one-to-many relationship hierarchy database tblProjects->tblLines->tblGroups->tblStations etc. And an Entity framework 6 model.

These entity framework classes all implement a base class "tblBase":

```
  public abstract class TblBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _id;
    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private Nullable<int> _coid;
    public Nullable<int> COID
    {
        get
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
            return _coid;
        }
        set
        {
            _coid = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

I have a treeview that allows me to select any node as the parent type, and currently I have a method for each type that allows me to reload all the child entities.

I would like to see how this could be made generic:

```
      private async static Task<bool> RefreshLinesAsync(LocalUser ThisUser, ProjectEntities DBContext, object Entity)
    {
        List<object> NonExistingNodes = new List<object>();
        var bContinue = false;
        var PassedEntity = Entity as TblBase;

        //Scan through all DB child entities and reload their DB values
       foreach (var SubEntity in DBContext.tblLines.Where(x => x.ProjectID == PassedEntity.ID).ToList())
        {
            await DBContext.Entry(SubEntity).ReloadAsync().ContinueWith(x =>
            {
                if (!x.IsFaulted)
                {
                    if ((SubEntity.COID.GetValueOrDefault() != 0) && (SubEntity.COID.GetValueOrDefault() != ThisUser.ID))
                        NotifyCOIDConflict(SubEntity, new CheckedOutArgs()
                        {
                            ConflictCOID = SubEntity.COID.GetValueOrDefault()
                        });
                    bContinue = true; 
                }
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
            if (bContinue)
                //Continue to child entities method
                await RefreshGroupsAsync(ThisUser, DBContext, SubEntity);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private async static Task<bool> RefreshGroupsAsync(LocalUser ThisUser, ProjectEntities DBContext, object Entity)
    {
        List<object> NonExistingNodes = new List<object>();

        var bContinue = false;
        var PassedEntity = Entity as TblBase;

        foreach (var SubEntity in DBContext.tblGroups.Where(x => x.LineID == PassedEntity.ID).ToList())
        {
            await DBContext.Entry(SubEntity).ReloadAsync().ContinueWith(x =>
            {
                if (!x.IsFaulted)
                {
                    if ((SubEntity.COID.GetValueOrDefault() != 0) && (SubEntity.COID.GetValueOrDefault() != ThisUser.ID))
                        NotifyCOIDConflict(SubEntity, new CheckedOutArgs()
                        {
                            ConflictCOID = SubEntity.COID.GetValueOrDefault()
                        });
                    bContinue = true;
                }
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
            if (bContinue)
                await RefreshStationsAsync(ThisUser,DBContext, SubEntity);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The only method I can see useful is Set(), although it does not provide a Where() method, which is critical since I do not want to retrieve the entire table.

Comment: There is a method in dbcontext called Set<TEntity>() that has Where() function. You can use it with your base type: `DBContext.Set<TblBase>().Where(...)`.

Comment: @Seididieci I have tried that, I get an exception that my tblBase is not part of my Model

Comment: Sorry I didn't noticed that your base class is abstract... What about making your function generic as `private async static Task<bool> RefreshLinesAsync<TEntity>(LocalUser ThisUser, ProjectEntities DBContext, TEntity Entity)`?

Comment: @Seididieci I could try that, could you show me roughly how that method would look?

Answer (score 1):

You can make your functions generic. They maybe like this one:

```
private async static Task<bool> RefreshLinesAsync<TEntity>(LocalUser ThisUser, ProjectEntities DBContext, TEntity Entity) where TEntity : TblBase
{
    List<TEntity> NonExistingNodes = new List<TEntity>();
    var bContinue = false;
    var PassedEntity = Entity as TblBase;

    foreach (var SubEntity in DBContext.Set<TEntity>().Where(x => (x as TblBase).ProjectID == PassedEntity.ID).ToList()) {
       //Your other code here...
    }
}
```

The where clause in function definition, make you sure that this method can be called only with subclasses of TblBase.

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that you need to cast SubEntity as TblBase inside foreach loop to use it...

EDIT (in response of comments):

If you need to get all TblBase subclasses from your entity, you cannot make your function so generic if you keep them in separate tables: It will became hardly mantainable when you have to add more subclasses.

I suggest you to use a single table through Table Per Hierarchy (see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) article in MSDN) changing TblBase from abstract to concrete class, then you can get all of them this way:

```
 var allSubClassEntities = DBContext.Set<TblBase>();
```

Comment: I have implemented that, but the problem now is that my SubEntity is of the same type as my Entity, and I need it to assume the type of the child entities.

Comment: Also, the expressions only allow me to access the tblBase properties. ProjectID is a navigation property of my tblLines. I need to specify the navigation property somehow.